# Optimisation linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Silly question maybe - but, what would be faster:

-Deleting an item from a linked list every time an item is gone (whatever that item might be)

-Just marking the record as dead and overwriting it after x amount of time or conditions.

Would I not use less cpu time by avoiding all the removing and inserting rather than just overwriting.

Comment: Sounds like you need extra overhead and branching to do what you want.  My gut tells me that might be slower.  One way to find out is code it and profile it.

Comment: The problem is not the number of instructions, but the fragmented heap / page faults.

Comment: Use a vector :D

Comment: How many thousands of deletes are we talking about?

Comment: ***-Just marking the record as dead and overwriting it after x amount of time or conditions.*** Are you getting the node out of the list (perhaps moving it to a deleted list) or leaving it in and marking it as dead?

Comment: Hi drescherjm, I would leave it in. I realize that would still make me have to iterate over it, but i dont expect more then 50, 100 nodes to ever appear in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers all.

Comment: ***but i dont expect more then 50, 100 nodes to ever appear in the list.*** With that few nodes I wouldn't expect that much of a difference in execution speed between the non optimized and optimized versions.

Comment: Yeah, it was more a thought of mine, i.e. why delete when you can just overwrite the data, seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to find out is to use a profiler.

Keep in mind that there are other factors which are very important that you didn't specify in your question. For example, it makes a big difference if you *know* which element to delete, i.e. you have the pointer to it ready, or if you have to iterate over the linked list to find it. In that case, a vector could actually be several times faster than any linked list (depending on the number of elements) due to caching.

Comment: I would know item to delete, but i would still have to traverse the list to find it. I'm reading on vectors right now, but yes i will definitely test both methods out. Having said that for the amount of items i'm going to use i doubt it will make much difference, but it was something i wanted to know for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting is going to be faster.  If deleting involves freeing allocated memory from the heap, then overwriting will definitely be faster.  Memory allocation is relatively slow.  Plus, over time your list memory would get fragmented which might cause cache misses.  Even freeing memory that goes back into a memory manager of some sort would be slower since you have the overhead of managing the nodes of the list.

Comment: Yeah, i thought it would be obvious, but maybe there was something i missed. I guess there's a tradeoff between traversing the list, and deleting them, but my list is never going to be really big (50, 100 items max). Thanks!

Comment: out of the two options poonam gave, overwriting will be faster. But considering that they said they will be traversing the list often, I am pretty sure that a vector will be even faster, if the element count isn't in the millions.